# WAV file error while playing - need help in reconstruction

Tags: audio, wav

I have a wav file but when I open it, it doesn't play and gives an error and I have tried various players for this but no help.

I viewed the hex of the file as follows, copied first few lines only.

..D.........G..4;...B....M........E.A....M..E.;M.......3....M.9M..............E..E..E.........D..%.....E.;...i....M..E.k....d........o......|........E....U.....E....U......+..........]..@..........]..E.........Au..]......E..........z....]......E..E........

Please if anyone could help me on this.

Comment: That's not any HEX representation that I understand. It looks more like you've tried to read it as a text file - but even then, in a wav file you should see 'RIFF' . 'WAVE' and 'fmt' in the first few characters.

Comment: Why not put a link to the file? (unless this is not allowed by stack overflow? But I've seen it in other questions)

Comment: Here's the link to file if you couldd help....
http://www.sendspace.com/file/3hlri4

Comment: The file starts F0BA 0010 8B56 B9C6 ... don't know what that header means. The file also doesn't seem to have any readable text in it, which is unusual (could it be encrypted?) I tried opening it as raw PCM data in some common formats but didn't get any sensible output. A lot of the data doesn't really look like PCM audio data either - lots of sections of the same value repeated over and over.

Answer (score 0):

The file you have is not a valid wav file.

The wav file format specifies that the header and data should follow a specific format (a wav file is a type of riff file).

If you compare the hex you have against https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/ it looks like the file you have is missing the "riff" specifier and has no "fmt" chunk.

Mike